# Using Steering Wheel in Unity

Tags: unity, gamepad

Is there any way to use a steering wheel in Unity? All I find online is people with the same problem. The numbering on the axis are not the same as with keyboard input. In some cases left is 1 and as you turn it more to the left it gradually goes down to 0 even though you are still turning left

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we can infer from the problem you are actually explaining, yes. You can most certainly use a steering wheel controller. The problem you face is in your *assumption* of how the axis and buttons will be handled, in the first place.

To give a better example, let's take a look at the Xbox 360 controller, [courtesy of the Unity 3D Wiki](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtkOP.png):

[image: The same controller has different axis references across various platforms.]

As you can see from the diagrams, and the table of axis values provided by the [Unity 3D Wiki](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Xbox360Controller#Bindings), we simply can not assume a standard in interpreting input - across controller type ***or*** platform.

By default, nothing should *invert* the axis, either. So if the controller reports "left" as 0, and "center" as 1, you will just have to accept that this is the way the controller outputs, and cater for it on your end.

You can certainly work out the correct axis and inputs through trial and error. Without access to documentation, which is made harder by the fact that input labeling could be unique to both the manufacturer and model of the steering wheel, this might be the easiest solution. There are two ways this could work for you; the automatic approach is by far the easiest, but you may need to take a slower manual approach, if the automatic approach does not expose the complete functionality of the controller you intend to use.

*Keep in mind that this will only tell us what input axis are being used relative to your own operating system and/or drivers. As we have already seen, these values may change across configurations.*

### Automatically identifying each axis

The first option you have is to simply build your game, as is, and use the pre-startup Input Configuration Manager to identify the axis.

Build your game, and run the `.exe` you create. Before the game starts, you are shown a configuration menu. Select 'Input' to look at the input fields you have made available through the Input Manager.

[image: Unity asks you to set input before playing a build game, allowing you to directly identify the labels unity gives to each individual input.]

Simply click on an input, under *Primary* or *Secondary*, and you will be prompted to *Press a button or key*. Make the desired input on your controller, and observe the new value it gets registered as.

Note that an axis input shows the positive (+) and negative (-) values as separate controls. This is especially useful, and it may not necessarily be safe to assume that your controller will correctly output opposite directions as the same axis. It may be safer to confirm that the opposite direction on the controller ***does*** correctly register as the opposite direction on the axis, and if not, make a mental note of it.

### Manually checking each axis

You have the option of exposing each axis through a basic script. By creating public floats to update with each available axis, you can see the input values of the many input axis, while providing the desired input with the controller. In turn, you can identify what axis change when you perform certain inputs, and what values they change to. This is quite cumbersome; Unity handles 28 separate axis! I have provided an example of such an implementation, with the presumption that we would only need to check the first 10.

---

First, we need to ensure the Input Manager is correctly set up to forward the intended axis. Ensure that you have an entry for each axis in your Input Manager, and that each one has the correct "axis" selected. For example, the X axis is labelled 'X axis', and your third axis is labelled '3rd axis'.

[image: Unity Input Manager set up to represent the first 10 input axis]

---

Next, create a script, and make a `public float` for each axis. Name them using the same naming conventions, and ensure that each one is passed the correct `Input.GetAxis()` in an update function.

```
public float x, y, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten;

void Update()
{
    x = Input.GetAxis("X");
    y = Input.GetAxis("Y");
    three = Input.GetAxis("Three");
    four = Input.GetAxis("Four");
    five = Input.GetAxis("Five");
    six = Input.GetAxis("Six");
    seven = Input.GetAxis("Seven");
    eight = Input.GetAxis("Eight");
    nine = Input.GetAxis("Nine");
    ten = Input.GetAxis("Ten");
}
```

---

We now have an inspector element that gives us visual feedback of our axis input! While in play-testing, with this script active and visible on the inspector, you can now see the values being stored in your Input Manager. Through trial and error, you can manually work out which axis is represented by which functionality, and what values are passed.

---

Ultimately, there is a lot of special cases to consider, when using *any* non-default controller. At the end of the day, it might be of better consideration to simply set your game up for use with a default gaming controller, or even the keyboard and/or mouse.

The user can still set up their steering wheel during the startup configuration, and this ensures your control scheme matches their unique setup. The only down side to this is that Unity does not save custom key mappings, by default. Unless you implement a way to record customised key mappings to reuse them later, the user would have to configure their controller every time they play the game.

Comment: If I could give you more than one upvote, I would

Comment: @JohnDemetriou actually you could start a bounty :)